# Create a TypeConverter between existing types

Tags: wpf, typeconverter

From the docs, it looks like I can only use a TypeConverter on classes that I create.  Is that true, or is it possible to create a TypeConverter to use on existing framework types?  Specifically, I'd like to convert a boolean value of true to a BlurEffect and a value of false to null.

The idea is to bind the Effect property on my view to a boolean property on my ViewModel and have the view blur when the value is true.

Comment: You would usually use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) for that task.

Comment: @Clemens Perfect.  You can put that as an answer if you want credit for it.

Comment: This question is misleading.  You don't need a `TypeConverter`. which is a converter from literal values (like `0 10`) to literal values (like `Thickness(0,10,0,10)`).  You need an `IValueConverter`, which converts bound values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to register a TypeConverter for converting types in a Binding.

Instead you can set the [Binding.Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) property to an object that implements [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).